# I want to create a AWS RDS trigger to call my AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I want to create a AWS RDS trigger to call my AWS Lambda function. Is this possible ?

Comment: What database engine are you using? Is it MYSQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that only if you are using AWS Aurora

> You can invoke a Lambda function from an Aurora MySQL DB cluster in the following ways:
>
> ```
> Invoking a Lambda Function with an Aurora MySQL Native Function
> Invoking a Lambda Function with an Aurora MySQL Stored Procedure
> ```

Refer [Invoking a Lambda Function from an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.Lambda.html) for more details

Comment: I want to trigger a lambda function from AWS RDS and not from Aurora.

Comment: AWS Aurora also comes under RDS as one of the database engines. So if you use that as the database in RDS it is possible and if you use some other database in RDS then it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

There is no  direct way for trigger Lambda functions from RDS.

You can use SNS topics with RDS.

lets read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateEventSubscription.html) doc.

Then you can attach that SNS topic  to lambda function.